# aws runInstance resources denied explicitly allow all resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am having a painful bug, when I use the Iam visual editor to create a role to run the instance, if I create two policies, the first when I allow all resources implicitly:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
    }
]
```

}

however, if I specify the resources I explicitly allow all resources, I get this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole",
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:launch-template/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:placement-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:capacity-reservation/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "arn:aws:elastic-inference:*:*:elastic-inference-accelerator/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:elastic-gpu/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

when I simulate runInstance in the EC2-Classic-InstanceStore the first policy in the IAM policy simulator passes, however the second one doesn't. is there a resource that aws hasn't listed in its IAM visual editor? see attached pics for results:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=153361)? Policy Simulator is not perfect. But in a similar case to yours, an exact resource had to be provided for it to work properly.

Comment: You might be able to check CloudTrail to obtain more information about what it was trying to do, and why it was denied.